# presentModelViewController not working

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have navigationController in my appdelegate class
&
passing a viewController(RootViewController) in it.
In RootViewController i m using a custom UItableViewCell.
In the UITableViewCell class i have a UIButton.
on button click i want to navigate to some other page(sampleViewController)
so on button click i m using

```
-(void)btnClick
{
[self.viewController presentModelViewController:sampleViewController animated:YES];

}
```

but this does't navigate to sampleViewController.
where i'm making a mistake?
Please help/suggest me friens for the above.

Comment: This code looks ok. Put breakpoint and/or log message in that method to check if it actually gets called.

Comment: i have tried log/breakpoint does't getting any clue.

Comment: are you sure that there will be [self.viewController presentModelViewController:sampleViewController animated:YES];
on button click.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly just a simple typo - the correct method name is presentModalViewController:animated: (**Modal**, not Model)

Comment: NO Simon  this is not the problem.  The problem is that when i print NSLog(@"%@",sampleViewController.view) it's giving null.

Answer (score 0):

Did you connect your button's onTouchUp event?  Is the button being called?